# Silverlight: how to use a scroll viewer to wrap a list view without specifying height?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit, scrollviewer

I have a control that has a list that varies in length greatly. This control appears in various places meaning that i cannot calculate its position and desired height easily.

Moreover all I want is for the scrollviewer to simply size itself according to its parent. currently it insists on sizing itself according to the content.

currently when i have a list that exceeds the height of the screen the whole control extends off the bottom and the scrollviewer shows no bar (because it has stretched to the heigth of the contents and so thinks it is not required).

I've not included code as the object graph is fairly deep.

What i am looking for is a set of conditions that would cause the scrollviewer to resize itself according to its content rather than its parent.

I have it working in a similar situation involving grids and datagrids, the unique part of this control is that there is a list containing controls.

Any ideas? I would prefer solutions that don't require use of code behind - but im really not in a position to be choosey.

Comment: You question contains apparently contradictory statements "all I want is for the scrollviewer to simply size itself according to its parent"  AND  "What i am looking for is a set of conditions that would cause the scrollviewer to resize itself according to its content"  Please clarify?

Comment: I don't think it does at all. What i want is the first statement, I need to establish the conditions in the second statement because eliminating them is how i can achieve it. I am simply providing the conditions that an answer needs to meet in order to be useful as they will fix the problem in the question. If you answer one of those statements you will probably at least implicitly answer the other as well, as they are negations of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Here are common reasons that come to mind that would allow a scroll viewer to size to its contents rather than to its "parent":-

- It's placed on a `Canvas` or a `StackPanel`
- It's assigned to a `Grid` row/column with it's Horizontal or Vertical alignment not set to Stretch and its content size is less than the size of the row or column.

Its ultimately upto the containing panel how it chooses to size a child element so its not really possible to dictate this completely from code inside the child.

Comment: unfortunatley neither of the conditions are true. I have deliberatley gone through and removed all references to stretch and every control is based around a grid.

Comment: @John: I think we have little chance of understanding your problem without a small chunk of xaml that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: probably, will figure out how to reproduce it.